# Add an abstract for the appendix

Tags: formatting

I would like to add a small abstract to the appendix part of my thesis document. This appendix must be before the first appendix (Appendix A).

The goal is to briefly describe the appendix as they consist of articles that I would like to add as annex.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion for abstracts in a thesis is that they should be typeset just like chapters; here's a possible setup:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{emptypage} % I recommend it

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Abstract}

\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter

\chapter{The thesis}

\lipsum

\appendix

\chapter*{Abstract for the appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract for the appendix}

The appendix will contain some articles.

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first article (data about it)

\item The second article (data about it)
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{First article}

\lipsum

\chapter{Second article}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```